# Как убрать ссылку "Просмотр корзины" которая появляется после добавления товара в корзину? woocommerce (wordpress)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

я создал свою собственную кнопку добавления товара в корзину по аналогии с кнопкой, которая вызывается с помощью шорткода. Так вот дело в том, что после добавления товара в корзину появляется ссылка на переход в саму корзину. Я бы хотел убрать данную ссылку.

Вот код моей кнопки:

```
<a href="/wordpress/?removed_item=1&add-to-cart=132" data-product_id="132" class="button add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart order active">В корзину</a>
```

Я конечно могу ее скрыть с помощью css, но мне кажется что это не правильно и что есть более элегантный способ.

P.s. Я использовал поисковик для поиска решения, но у меня не получилось найти ответ. В любом случае спасибо за внимание :)

Comment: Еще появилась мысль удалять этот элемент из DOM с помощью js.

Answer (score -1):

```
.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
    display: none;
}
```